# New build boots to bios spash then cycles

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I'm building a new computer. See the build list below.
It will boot to the BIOS splash screen but then just cycles over and over.
I've reset the BIOS and the system is down to the base, using onboard video (video card not installed), no HD or other connected to MB, 1 stick of ram.
PS seems to boot fine. The CPU fan spins up.
When the HD is connected I hear it spinning up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Gigabyte GA-F2A88XM-D3H A88X FM2+ SATA 3 USB 3.0, HDMI mATX Motherboard

AMD FM Socket A10 5800K Quad Core 3.8Ghz with Radeon HD 7660D GPU

Kingston HyperX FURY Blue HX316C10FK2/16 DDR3-1600 16GB(2x8GB)/1Gx64

GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 960 4GB WINDFORCE 2X OC EDITION

Cooler Master V Series 650W Compact Fully Modular 80 PLUS Gold Power Supply

Comment: What media are you trying to boot from?

Comment: If you have reset the bios, and you are booting from a HDD with a Windows system installed, check that you have the SATA mode set to AHCI  - Try that and let us know

Comment: @Tyson, I've tried booting with an without any media. As I never get past the boot splash screen, I can't get into the bios setup, I don't "see" the media.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, Can't sent the SATA mode as I haven't gotten into the BIOS setup, don't get past the BIOS splash screen. And yes I've tried to put the "DEL" key to enter the BIOS setup.

Comment: You need to remove the battery from the motherboard for 5 mins, then replace. see if it boots - Remove the gtx960 as well before doing this and use the onboard video.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, Thank you. Yes I did that as well. I've also talked to Gigabyte support and have RMA'd the MB.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the folks will recommend flashing the BIOS only if there is a specific need, and on the Gigabyte boards, using the QFlash appl after downloading the BIOS file on a floppy or USB flash drive. Few will recommend using the Windows @BIOS because of problems and risk of updating with that utility.

Are you able to get to your BIOS splash screen before the bootloop occurs? If so, you can click on  key without getting into the BIOS itself and update the BIOS from a flash drive. Or if you backed up the original BIOS file before using @BIOS, you might be able to reload that.

4-2-1 Updating the BIOS with the Q-Flash Utility
A. Before You Begin:
1.

1. From GIGABYTE's website, download the latest compressed BIOS update file that matches your motherboard model.

   2. Extract the file and save the new BIOS file (e.g. p35ds3l.f1) to your floppy disk, USB flash drive, or hard drive. Note: The USB flash drive or hard drive must use FAT32/16/12 file system.
   3. Restart the system. During the POST, press the  key to enter Q-Flash. Note: You can access Q-Flash by either pressing the  key during the POST or pressing the  key in BIOS Setup. However, if the BIOS update file is saved to a hard drive in RAID/AHCI mode or a hard
      drive attached to an independent IDE/SATA controller, use the  key during the POST to access Q-Flash.

Because BIOS flashing is potentially risky, please do it with caution. Inadequate BIOS flashing
may result in system malfunction.

If that's not successful, you should follow the instructions on page 29, to reset the CMOS. Requires turning off and unplugging your computer, then shorting out the Clr CMOS pins as instructed.

**CLR_CMOS (Clearing CMOS Jumper)**

Use this jumper to clear the CMOS values (e.g. date information and BIOS configurations) and reset the CMOS values to factory defaults. To clear the CMOS values, place a jumper cap on the two pins to temporarily short the two pins or use a metal object like a screwdriver to touch the two
pins for a few seconds.

- Always turn off your computer and unplug the power cord from the power outlet before clearing the CMOS values.

  - After clearing the CMOS values and before turning on your computer, be sure to remove the jumper cap from the jumper. Failure to do so may cause damage to the motherboard.
  - After system restart, go to BIOS Setup to load factory defaults (select Load Optimized Defaults) or manually configure the BIOS settings (refer to Chapter 2, "BIOS Setup," for BIOS configurations).

That should reset it back to the initial BIOS version, to at least get you going.

Comment: 1. I'm not able to get beyond the splash screen so I can't upgrade the BIOS. Yes I have tried every key to get to the BIOS setup. Doesn't work. I can see the mouse so I think it's at least recognizing the mouse and keyboard. 2. I cleared the BIOS using the jumper method, this didn't solve the problem either.